# Symfony Serializing Entities with children to XML

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm trying to serialize an entity with children to an XML file using the buildin serializer from Symfony. The problem is that the serializer doesn't
format the collection of children in the xml the way I expected.

I initiate the serializer as follows:

```
    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();

    $normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
        return $object->getId();
    });

    $this->serializer = new Serializer(
        [
            $normalizer,
            new GetSetMethodNormalizer(),
            new ArrayDenormalizer()
        ],
        [new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()]
    );
```

And call the serializer like this:

```
    $this->serializer->serialize(
        $entityCollection,
        'xml',
        [
            'xml_format_output' => true,
            'xml_root_node_name' => 'events'
        ]
    );
```

Which results in the following XML:

```
 <item key="140">
      <id/>
      <name>Lorum ipsum</name>
      <lastEdited/>
      <url>Lorum ipsum</url>
      <region>Limburg</region>
      <description>Lorum ipsum</description>
      <location/>
      <contact/>
      <content><![CDATA[<p>Lorum ipsum</p>]]></content>
      <priceChild/>
      <priceAdult/>
      <startTime>15:00:00</startTime>
      <endTime>15:45:00</endTime>
      <eventDates/>
      <eventImages>
        <id/>
        <url>herfstvoorstelling.jpg</url>
      </eventImages>
      <eventImages>
        <id/>
        <url>test.jpg</url>
      </eventImages>
    </item>
```

As you can see the `<eventImages>` node are represented twice where I expected it to have the following structure:

```
      <eventImages>
        <eventImage>
          <id/>
          <url>herfstvoorstelling.jpg</url>
        </eventImage>
        <eventImage>
          <id/>
          <url>test.jpg</url>
        </eventImage>
      </eventImages>
```

The entities used:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\EventRepository")
 */
class Event
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lastEdited;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $region;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $location;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $contact;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $priceChild;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $priceAdult;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $startTime;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $endTime;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\EventDate", mappedBy="event")
     */
    private $eventDates;

    /**
     * @MaxDepth(2)
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\EventImage", mappedBy="event")
     */
    private $eventImages;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->eventDates = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->eventImages = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastEdited(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastEdited;
    }

    public function setLastEdited(string $lastEdited): self
    {
        $this->lastEdited = $lastEdited;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUrl(): ?string
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

    public function setUrl(string $url): self
    {
        $this->url = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRegion(): ?string
    {
        return $this->region;
    }

    public function setRegion(string $region): self
    {
        $this->region = $region;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLocation(): ?string
    {
        return $this->location;
    }

    public function setLocation(string $location): self
    {
        $this->location = $location;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContact(): ?string
    {
        return $this->contact;
    }

    public function setContact(string $contact): self
    {
        $this->contact = $contact;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(string $content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPriceChild(): ?string
    {
        return $this->priceChild;
    }

    public function setPriceChild(string $priceChild): self
    {
        $this->priceChild = $priceChild;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPriceAdult(): ?string
    {
        return $this->priceAdult;
    }

    public function setPriceAdult(string $priceAdult): self
    {
        $this->priceAdult = $priceAdult;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStartTime(): ?string
    {
        return $this->startTime;
    }

    public function setStartTime(string $startTime): self
    {
        $this->startTime = $startTime;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEndTime(): ?string
    {
        return $this->endTime;
    }

    public function setEndTime(string $endTime): self
    {
        $this->endTime = $endTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|EventDate[]
     */
    public function getEventDates(): Collection
    {
        return $this->eventDates;
    }

    public function addEventDate(EventDate $eventDate): self
    {
        if (!$this->eventDates->contains($eventDate)) {
            $this->eventDates[] = $eventDate;
            $eventDate->setEvent($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEventDate(EventDate $eventDate): self
    {
        if ($this->eventDates->contains($eventDate)) {
            $this->eventDates->removeElement($eventDate);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($eventDate->getEvent() === $this) {
                $eventDate->setEvent(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|EventImage[]
     */
    public function getEventImages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->eventImages;
    }

    public function addEventImage(EventImage $eventImage): self
    {
        if (!$this->eventImages->contains($eventImage)) {
            $this->eventImages[] = $eventImage;
            $eventImage->setEvent($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEventImage(EventImage $eventImage): self
    {
        if ($this->eventImages->contains($eventImage)) {
            $this->eventImages->removeElement($eventImage);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($eventImage->getEvent() === $this) {
                $eventImage->setEvent(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

}

<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\EventImageRepository")
 */
class EventImage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Event", inversedBy="eventImages")
     */
    private $event;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUrl(): ?string
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

    public function setUrl(?string $url): self
    {
        $this->url = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEvent(): ?Event
    {
        return $this->event;
    }

    public function setEvent(?Event $event): self
    {
        $this->event = $event;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I can't find out what I'm missing or if it is possible to achieve this with the default serializer from Symfony.

Comment: you might be using to many normalizers; try excluding the `ArrayDenormalizer`; are you sure you need that too ?

Comment: @zedling Tried it without `ArrayDenormalizer` unfortunately it still returns the same xml. This instance of the serializer is used for multiple tasks thats why it was added.

Comment: it might be your Entity; could you edit and include it in the question ?

Comment: also please include your serialization definition too

Comment: you might want to use the jms serializer boundle, it will give you better control over the structure of the results

Comment: @zedling updated the questions and included the entities. I have read about the jms serializer bundle, the problem is that the standard symfony one is already pretty integrated. So solving it with the default one would have my preference but well if it can't be done it can't be done.

Comment: I'm just shooting in the dark, but try adding `fetch="EAGER"` to the association mapping, and maybe mock up some `eventDates` too, to see if they behave differently; it might be a load order bug; again just a hunch

Comment: @zedling I tried your suggestion by adding `fetch="EAGER"` unfortunately without success. In the meanwhile I also have been testing out the serialization with the JMS serializer bundle like you advised and it just works exactly how I want it to work. So I guess even if it requires some more testing implementing it, it is the best solution. Thanks for your help!